# How to get an object key from a Map?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I create a Map object and set some keys to values and end up with something like this:

{"a" => 1, "b" => "hello", 3 => {"c": true}, {a: 1} => "hi"};

I can access the "a", "b", and 3 keys by using `myMap.get("a")`, `myMap.get("b")`, and `myMap.get(3)` respectively, but I can't seem to do `myMap.get({a:1})`. This probably has to do with the fact that objects are passed by reference.

How do I access the value of keys that are objects using the Map API?

Comment: This is not a valid JS `Map` syntax, it looks more like PHP?

Comment: "*This probably has to do with the fact that objects are passed by reference.*" - yes.  "*How do I access the value of keys that are objects using the Map API?*" - well, use the **same** object.